# Checking if Array exist?

Tags: php, arrays, post

There is post of select form like:

```
<select name="option[color][0]">
<select name="option[color][1]">
// option[color][2] isnt posted
```

Some products doesnt have that select, and then when I try to get them from post, each time if select isn't posted, im getting error like:

> Undefined offset: 2

How to check if something is posted?
Tried:

```
$ids       = $_POST['id'];
$option = $_POST['option'];

foreach ($ids as $key => $id)
{
   //Undefined offset: 2
   if( $option['color'][$key] )
   {
      $_SESSION[$key]['option']['color'] = $option['color'][$key];
   }

   //Undefined offset: 2
   if( !empty($option['color'][$key]) )
   {
      $_SESSION[$key]['option']['color'] = $option['color'][$key];
   }

   //Undefined offset: 2
   if( isset($option['color'][$key]) )
   {
      $_SESSION[$key]['option']['color'] = $option['color'][$key];
   }

   //... etc
}
```

Etc.... what ever I try, there is error :(
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [array_key_exists](http://php.net/array_key_exists) to see if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

if it is always 0,1,2 or any line of consecutive integers you could do `if(count($option['color']) > $key ){}`

Comment: sorry should be just `>` not `>=`

Comment: This also workd, but allready gave best answer. Thanks one more time

Answer (score 1):

`isset($option['color'][$key])` is the way to go.

Check the exact line of code the error occurs when you still get it using `isset()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( isset($option['color'][$key]) )
{
  $_SESSION[$key]['option']['color'] = $option['color'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `isset` or `empty`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

for example:

```
if (isset($array['idx'])){ ... }
if (!empty($array['idx'])){ ... }
```